# json_encode formatted table

Tags: php, jquery, json

Im using jquery to fetch from a PHP file some data. I get the data but it outputs only the first row from the fetched table.
Thats my code in php

```
$data = array();
while ($rowtwo = $queryresult->fetch_assoc()){
   $data['id'] = json_encode($rowtwo['id']);
   $data['Name'] = json_encode($rowtwo['Name']);
   $data['Surname'] = json_encode($rowtwo['Surname']);
   $data['Time'] = json_encode($rowtwo['Time']);
   $data['Date'] = json_encode($rowtwo['Date']);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

And thats my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$.getJSON("http://www.blablabla.com/phpfile.php", function (data){
$("#Id").html( data.id );
$("#Name").html( data.Name);
$("#Surname").html( data.Surname);
$("#Time").html( data.Time );
$("#Date").html( data.Date );
});
},1000);
});
```

And the result is only one row , but in my table i have 5 rows in it.

Comment: Can you add a snippet showing the JSON structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are replacing each value on `$data`. You have to push each entry on `$data` array

```
$data = array();
while ($rowtwo = $queryresult->fetch_assoc()){
    $temp = array();

    $temp['id'] = $rowtwo['id'];
    $temp['Name'] = $rowtwo['Name'];
    $temp['Surname'] = $rowtwo['Surname'];
    $temp['Time'] = $rowtwo['Time'];
    $temp['Date'] = $rowtwo['Date'];

    $data[] = $temp;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

On your `jQuery` code. You have to loop.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="mydangertwo"> 
    </tbody> 
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://www.blablabla.com/phpfile.php", function (data){

            var htmlText = "";

            for ( var key in data ) {
               //Access each entry  using the variables below
               //data[ key ].id
               //data[ key ].Name
               //data[ key ].Surname
               //data[ key ].Time
               //data[ key ].Date

               htmlText += "<tr class='danger'>";
               htmlText += "<td>" + data[ key ].id + "</td>";
               htmlText += "<td>" + data[ key ].Name + "</td>";
               htmlText += "<td>" + data[ key ].Surname + "</td>";
               htmlText += "<td>" + data[ key ].Time + "</td>";
               htmlText += "<td>" + data[ key ].Date + "</td>";
               htmlText += "</tr> ";
          }

          //Append to mydangertwo
          $( "#mydangertwo" ).append( htmlText );
        });
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Also he doesnt need to json_encode every time on assigning. can just do it once at the end

Comment: Hello there! Could you please explain  how  would i use the for loop in my HTML table?I mean how would i say those data to appear in my html table which is that :                                                                           
        <tbody id="mydangertwo"> 
 <tr class="danger">
 <td id="id"></td>
 <td id="name"></td>
 <td id="surname"></td>
 <td id="time"></td>
 <td id="date"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

Comment: @Eddie can you tell me how can i do it work with my approach? i mean the $("#Id").html( data.id );
$("#Name").html( data.Name);
$("#Surname").html( data.Surname);
$("#Time").html( data.Time );
$("#Date").html( data.Date );

Comment: @Β_origin if you have several rows or entries, you **cant** use `#id `because `id` should be unique. It only works if you have one entry

Comment: @Β_origin Please accept my answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Eddie, yes now it worked! The only changed that i had to make was the .append (htmlText) to .html(htmlText) , cause .append method was looping the values all the time! Really thank you. If you want just explain the code and how it worked.